# Angular 2 : Give value to button based on dropdown menu value

Tags: html, css, angular

I am new to angular 2.

I have a button and a drop down which is appeared. When I click on any of the option then its value should be given to the button .

```css
.common_select_box {
 width: 100%;
}

.common_select_box button {
 border: thin #cfdadd solid;
 border-radius: 0 !important;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 7.45px 12px;
 border-radius: 1.5px !important;
}

.common_select_box button .caret {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 margin-right: 2px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 border-top: 6px dashed;
 border-right: 6px solid transparent;
 border-left: 6px solid transparent;
 position: absolute;
 top: 14px;
 right: 5px;
}

.common_select_box ul.dropdown-menu {
 border: 1px solid #cfdadd;
 border-radius: 2px;
 box-shadow: none !important;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0px;
}

.common_select_box ul.dropdown-menu li {
 padding: 5px 15px;
 font-size: 12px;
  list-style-type:none;
}

.common_select_box ul.dropdown-menu li:hover {
 background: #edf1f2 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="common_select_box">
                        <!--give open class to below div when clicking on button-->
                        <div class="input-group-btn dropdown {{dropdown1? 'open':''}}" (click)="dropdown1=!dropdown1">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default font_size_12 no_box_shadow ticket_info_subline_text_color" dropdown-toggle="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" >Select &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="caret" style="color: #bfbfbf;"></span></button>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li >Option 1</li>
                              <li >Option 2</li>
                              <li >Option 3</li>
                              
                            </ul>
                        </div><!-- /btn-group -->
                    </div>
```

When I click on **option 1** . then its value should be given to **button** tag.

Any Help Would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work,

```
<div class="common_select_box">
<div class="input-group-btn dropdown {{dropdown1? 'open':''}}" 
(click)="dropdown1=!dropdown1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default font_size_12 no_box_shadow 
ticket_info_subline_text_color" dropdown-toggle=""
        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{selectedNav}}<span 
class="caret" style="color: #bfbfbf;"></span> </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li (click)="setNav(item)" *ngFor="let item of navs">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
```

in .ts file

```
export class PropertyComponent {
selectedNav: any; navs = ['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3']
ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedNav = 'select value';
}
setNav(nav){
    this.selectedNav = nav;
}
}
```